# keeping text selection active while selecting color

Tags: execcommand, jscolor

So I am using the [JSColor picker](http://jscolor.com/) to change the foreground of a selected text in conjunction with the [document.execCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method where you can send the command something along the lines of:

```
<input maxlength="5" class="color {required:false}" onchange="fmtEdit('Icontent','ForeColor',this.color)">
```

where the fmtEdit function looks like this:

```
function fmtEdit(I,command, optn, evnt){
 if((command=='forecolor') || (command=='hilitecolor')){
  this.getPallete(command, optn, evnt);
 }else{
  if($(I).contentWindow.document.queryCommandEnabled(command)){
   $(I).contentWindow.document.execCommand(command, false, optn);
   return true;
  }else return false;
 }
 $(I).contentWindow.focus();
}
```

the code works perfectly fine if I have the command sent from a button or image with the onClick event for example:

```
<img alt="Bold" title="Bold" class="butClass" src="bold.png" onClick="fmtEdit('Icontent','bold','')">
```

But the selected text looses focus once I click on the color picker field to select a color.

Is there a way to keep the selection on the selected text while I click on the color selector?

Thanks a lot!
gabster.

Comment: Text selection which is not within an `INPUT` or `TEXTAREA` elements will always lost if the user clicks on other area. So you'll need to save the selection when the mouse is moving out of the selected element(s). Then recreate the selection before exiting the `fmtEdit` function.

Comment: thanks Jay! Do you have a tip on how to do that? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I am using an iframe for the editor. I wonder if the same selection rule apply as for INPUT or TEXTAREA. Thanks!